# spacy getting tokens in the form of string instead on uint8

Tags: python, spacy

I am wondering if there is a way to use `tokenizer(s).to_array("LOWERCASE")` in the form of string instead of format uint8.

```
from spacy.lang.en import English 
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer

s = "Lets pray for the people that can be the victim of the possible eruption of Taal Volcano  keep safe everyone."

# Create nlp obj
nlp = English()
tokenizer = Tokenizer(nlp.vocab)
 
#Get a list of tokens through list comprehension
tokens = [word.text for word in tokenizer(s)]
#Out > ["Lets", "pray", "for", ... , "everyone"]

# But easier method where you can also can apply Lowercase to the tokens as well by using,
tokens = tokenizer(s).to_array("LOWER") 
#Out > array([565864407007422797, 10267499103039061205, ... ,13330460590412905967],dtype=uint64) 

#But the format you end with results is dtype Unit8
```

Is there a way within spacy to get this in string format?

It would make things like removing stopwords much easier

```
 sp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
 all_stop_words = sp.Defaults.stop_words
 token_without_stopwords = [word for word in tokenizer(s).to_array("LOWER") if word not in all_stopwords]
 # This will ofcourse not work since they are two diffrent sata types from what I understand.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not seem possible with `to_array` to get the string token list due to [`Doc.to_array` return type, `ndarray`](https://spacy.io/api/doc#to_array):

> Export given token attributes to a numpy `ndarray`. If `attr_ids` is a sequence of `M` attributes, the output array will be of shape `(N, M)`, where `N` is the length of the `Doc` (in tokens). If `attr_ids` is a single attribute, the output shape will be `(N,)`. You can specify attributes by integer ID (e.g. `spacy.attrs.LEMMA`) or string name (e.g. “LEMMA” or “lemma”). The values will be 64-bit integers.

You can use

```py
token_without_stopwords = [word for word in map(lambda x: x.text.lower(),tokenizer(s)) if word not in all_stopwords]
```

where `map(lambda x: x.text.lower(),tokenizer(s))` gets a map object with all the token texts in lower case.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this.

```
sp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
all_stop_words = sp.Defaults.stop_words
lower_words = [word.text.lower() for word in sp(s)]
filtered = [word for word in lower_words if word not in all_stopwords]
```